# Comparing non equal dimension data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, series

I am looking to compare 2 Series in Pandas. I have the following code

```
a = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4], index = [1, 2, 3, 4])
b = pd.Series([1, 1, 1], index = [1, 5, 4])
a[~a.eq(b)]
```

In the case when the Series is empty, i.e., no values have been added to it as yet.

```
b = pd.Series()
a[~a.eq(b)]
```

Both cases give me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 735, in wrapper
    raise ValueError('Series lengths must match to compare')
ValueError: Series lengths must match to compare
```

The value I am looking to arrive at is:

```
2   2
3   3
4   4
```

in the 1st case and the following in the latter case:

```
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
```

Comment: so you want to compare values or the indexes or both?

Comment: `and the following in the latter case` - can you explain more?

Comment: I want to compare values in overlapping indices

Comment: The latter case is when the series is empty.

Comment: compare values? meaning in overlapping indices you want rows where the values do not match?

Comment: Yes. when the indices match then compare.

Comment: What if there was an entry in b like `3 2` with 3 as index, 2 as value?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) for same indices:

```
print (b.reindex(a.index))
1    1.0
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    1.0
dtype: float64

print (a[~a.eq(b.reindex(a.index))])
2    2
3    3
4    4
dtype: int64
```

---

```
print (a[~a.eq(b.reindex(pd.Series([]).index))])
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
dtype: int64
```

Comment: What is the indexes do have non overlapping elements?

Comment: Can you create sample?

Comment: I want to compare the values not the indices. Will update again.

Comment: Index is unique. Basically what I want is to compare this with the previous set of values and select the new added or updated values. It starts with and empty series.

Comment: It is a bit problematic, because need same unique indexes always for comapring Series.